# Initialization of Mock object not being recorded

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am trying to test the successful call of my class's constructor, but it is not being recorded in my Mock object. I am using the `pytest`and `pytest-mock`libraries for unit testing and mocking, respectively.

Imagine I have the following class in the package `cryptocurrency`in the module `transaction.py`:

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test
```

And the following test in another package `tests` in the module `test_transaction.py`:

```
def test_constructor(mocker):
    mock_transaction = mocker.patch('cryptocurrency.transaction.Transaction', 
        autospec=True)
    Transaction('123')
    mock_transaction.assert_called_once()
```

Why is it that the test fails with the message:

`AssertionError: Expected 'Transaction' to have been called once. Called 0 times.`

Shouldn't the Mock the object be listening to the initialization of the class instance and record it?

EDIT: I got this question answered, but I have another similar scenario that still doesn't work. Imagine that the class `Transaction` also has the following method:

```
@classmethod
def new_transaction(cls, test)
    return cls(test)
```

and that the test is:

```
def test_new_transaction(mocker):
    mock_transaction = mocker.patch('cryptocurrency.transaction.Transaction', 
        autospec=True)
    Transaction.new_transaction('123')
    mock_transaction.assert_called_once()
```

I can't get it to working. I already tried changing the patch to `__name__ + 'Transaction'` like the answer suggested, but it still doesn't work. I feel like my initial solution should be the correct one since even though the test references a certain `Transaction` import, the `new_transaction()` method will interact with the original `Transactiion` at `cryptocurrency.transaction.Transaction`.

Comment: This behaviour is the correct one - you have patched `cryptocurrency.transaction.Transaction` class, not the `Transaction` you've imported in the current module. If you would e.g. call a function that imports and uses `cryptocurrency.transaction.Transaction`, the `mock_transaction` would apply. If you want to patch the class for this module, do smth like `mocker.patch(__name__ + '.Transaction', autouse=True)`. Also, consider checking the [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id5) section from the docs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works! But I have another similar scenario now that I can't get to work either. Check my edited question.

Comment: The class constructor is not called in `Transaction.new_transaction('123')`, so the behaviour is again correct. If you want to intercept `Transaction.new_transaction` function, then do it via `mock_transaction.new_transaction.assert_called_once()`.

Comment: Hmm but my intention is to intercept the constructor call inside `Transaction.new_transaction` and to make sure it is called. I have no interest in intercepting the method `Transaction.new_transaction` itself because I already know it's being called in the test. Is that possible?

Comment: Ehm, there is no constructor call in the expression `Transaction.new_transaction('123')`. It's a _class method_ which doesn't require to create a class instance. If you want to intercept constructor call, you have to call the constructor in the first place, e.g. via `Transaction('123').new_transaction()`, but then it's questionable whether `new_transaction` should be a class method in the first place.

Comment: But the constructor is being called inside `Transaction.new_transaction`. It's in the line `return cls(test)`. Since `cls` stands for the class `Transaction`, then that line will return an instance of a `Transaction`, which, in turn, calls its constructor. That's what I want to intercept

Comment: Indeed, you are absolutely right! Sorry, didn't pay enough attention to your example. Let me try it out myself.

Comment: You see, the problem with mocking with autospeccing is that although the signature of the class is retained (so all the methods and attributes are accessible), the logic of methods is not retained. So although `mock_transaction` has the class method `new_transaction`, it is not `Transaction.new_transaction` class method, but another mock instead. Autospeccing will give this new mock the signature checks (so e.g. calling `mock_transaction.new_transaction('123', '456')` will fail), but the original method will not be executed.

Comment: Regarding your actual question - if you want to pass a mock into the classmethod, you will need to unwrap the `@classmethod` decorator by using the `__func__` magic method: replace `Transaction.new_transaction('123')` with `Transaction.new_transaction.__func__(mock_transaction, '123')`. Good question btw, upvoted!

Comment: That solution works perfectly! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help!